# Creating two recyclerview by data from two different url on same activity using AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I am creating an application like Prime Videos (for learning purposes). So far I have created two sections of Latest Movies and Latest Tv Shows. I am using `AsyncTaskLoader` in background to fetch data from The Movie DB API.

The problem arising is when i need different data to populate both Tv and Movie recycler views. I am only able to send one URL inside `onCreateLoader()`.

How can i fetch data from different URLs and then populate both `RecyclerView` during `onLoadFinished()`.

This is my main activity-

```
@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    LatestMoviesAndShowLoader moviesAndShowsLoader =new LatestMoviesAndShowLoader(this, URL_LATEST_MOVIES);
    return moviesAndShowsLoader;
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows>> loader, ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows> data) {
    recyclerAdapterMovies =new RecyclerAdapterMovies(data, this );
    recyclerViewMovies.setAdapter(recyclerAdapterMovies);
    recyclerViewMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
}
```

This is my loader class-

```
public class LatestTvShowLoader extends android.support.v4.content.AsyncTaskLoader<ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows>> {
    private String URL;
    public LatestTvShowLoader(Context context, String URL) {
        super(context);
        this.URL=URL;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStartLoading() {
        super.onStartLoading();
        forceLoad();
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows> loadInBackground() {
        ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows> arrayList= QueryData.getData(URL);
        return arrayList;
    }
}
```

Comment: I guess You Should Try RxJava

Comment: I am trying to not use external libraries as much as I can. Is there anyway by which I can hard code it by all myself?

Comment: it`s Not Like what you think 
it`s Called Reactive Programming
Just Search About It

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass different `id` while initiating a loader and check the id inside your `onCreateLoader` and other `LoaderCallbacks` functions.

For example, you have your TV loader and Movie loader. Let us assume the loader ids are 1 and 2 respectively.

```
// Declare the variables globally
private final int LOADER_TV = 1;
private final int LOADER_MOVIE = 2;
```

Then inside your `onCreate` or `onCreateView` function, initialize the loader.

```
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_TV, null, this).forceLoad();
getLoaderManager().initLoader(LOADER_MOVIE, null, this).forceLoad();
```

Now inside your `onCreateLoader` just check the id and execute the query based on the id received from the initialization.

```
@Override
public Loader<ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows>> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
    if(id == LOADER_MOVIE) {
        LatestMoviesAndShowLoader moviesAndShowsLoader = new LatestMoviesAndShowLoader(this, URL_LATEST_MOVIES);
        return moviesAndShowsLoader;
    } else {
        LatestMoviesAndShowLoader moviesAndShowsLoader = new LatestMoviesAndShowLoader(this, URL_LATEST_TV);
        return moviesAndShowsLoader;
    }
}

@Override
public void onLoadFinished(Loader<ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows>> loader, ArrayList<LatestMoviesAndShows> data) {
    if(loader.getId() == LOADER_MOVIE) {
        recyclerAdapterMovies =new RecyclerAdapterMovies(data, this );
        recyclerViewMovies.setAdapter(recyclerAdapterMovies);
        recyclerViewMovies.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    } else {
        recyclerAdapterShows = new RecyclerAdapterMovies(data, this );
        recyclerAdapterShows.setAdapter(recyclerAdapterShows);
        recyclerAdapterShows.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    } 
}
```

Hope that helps!